# PDO prepared statement bind parameters once for different queries

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using `PDO prepared statements` to execute two queries:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM vocabulary WHERE  `type` = :type AND `lesson` = :lesson;
SELECT * FROM vocabulary WHERE  `type` = :type AND `lesson` = :lesson limit 100;
```

The first query to get the count works as expected and i get the row count.

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
foreach ($params as $key => $value)
    $stmt->bindValue(":" . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$sql .= " limit $limit;";
$sql = str_replace("count(*)", $columns, $sql);
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
```

But when executing the second query i get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

Therefore, I would like to know, if I have multiple queries where the parameters are exactly the same ,if I need to bind the same parameters again using

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value)
    $stmt->bindValue(":" . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or if there is a way to bind parameters only once.

Comment: Your `$stmt =` resets the value so it is no longer bound. You could build an array and pass it to both `execute` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have multiple queries where the parameters are exactly the same, do I need to bind the same parameters again using

Yes, of course.

Parameters are bound to each query, not to PDO or a database globally.

On a side note, with PDO you don't have to bind variables explicitly, so there is a solution to your "problem": just don't bind  at all but send your data directly into execute() as it shown in the Dharman's excellent answer

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to modify your SQL like this. Your code basically comes down to this:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM vocabulary WHERE  `type` = :type AND `lesson` = :lesson');
$stmt->execute($params);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$stmt = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM vocabulary WHERE  `type` = :type AND `lesson` = :lesson limit 100');
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
```